# What's the different between "android:textSize" and "textSize" in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

In AOSP Code ,there are many TextView Resource use `"textSize"` in `style.xml` to limit the text size, by in a normal alllication ,they use `"android:textSize"` to limit text size.

So what's the different between those two things?

Comment: The system's package name is `android`. If you see style attributes in AOSP, it's in `android` namespace, so `textSize` in AOSP is the same as `android:textSize` in an application project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `style.xml` file the textSize is used for mentioning default text size value of that style.
so whenever you call that style in your view you will get that size of text.

Other hand in `android:textSize` we hard code the text size of that view.

Hope that make sense.